# Bootstrap input not full width and no rounded corners

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot for the life of me figure out why these bootstrap form fields are not full width and do not have rounded corners like they are supposed to. The bootstrap CSS is loading, I have no errors in my console, I have tried to add `width: 100%;` in my CSS, which loads after the bootstrap CSS, to no avail. Can someone please help?

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your demo?

Comment: why you are input-group, please replace it form-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why you are using `input-group` class? Please replace it on `form-group` class.

`.input-group` class, in bootstrap it's property define table, `.input-group .form-control` this property define `display:table-cell`;

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!